# Is it possible to use SVN and CVS simultaneously with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, cvs

I've been using **Tourtist-SVN** locally on a project for version control of my code.  I develop with **Eclipse** and will often import shared code using it's built in **CVS** module.

Soon I will be be moving my local **SVN** repository to another server in order to work with other developers.

I'm wondering if it's possible in **Eclipse** to continue to use **both CVS** for importing and updating some contributed code and at the same time use another **Eclipse SVN module** to version control my code.

Does anyone have experience using such a workflow model?  Will it be a waste of time to try to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem using both the built-in CVS support and one of the two major SVN plugins for different projects in the same workspace. I haven't tried using SVN and CVS for the same project, but I believe that it should in fact be possible as long as each VCS is configured to ignore the other's metadata directories.

Comment: So essentially just tell CVS to ignore any folder that ends in .svn and vise-versa for SVN.  But what what happens if my Colleagues don't set their environments that way too?  Will we all have to agree to do the same thing?

Comment: @DKinzer: If someone uses only one of the VCSs, he'll never get the other's metadata, so there should be no problem. The real problem is keeping the repositories in synch and the doubled potential for messed-up merges. I really wouldn't advise, and can't see any conceivable advantage in, keeping the same project in two different VCSs (as opposed to keeping disjunct sub-projects in two different VCSs, that's not such a problem).